# Square on my canvas appears for a second and then disappears

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

This is a whole project so if there are constraints or variables not used, ignore them.

```
const WIDTH = 640;
const HEIGHT = 480;
const PLAYER_SIZE = 20;
const REPAINT_DELAY = 50;
const EASY_DELAY = 1750;
const MODERATE_DELAY = 1000;
const HARD_DELAY = 750;
const MAX_BLOCKS = 100;
var canvas;
var ctx;
var playerX = 310;
var playerY = 230;
var DX = 0;
var DY = 0;

window.onload = init;

function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
  ctx.fillRect(playerX, playerY, PLAYER_SIZE, PLAYER_SIZE);
  window.onkeydown = keyArrows;
  return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function draw() {
  clearCanvas();

  /*
  ** I think this is where something is going wrong.
  ** I tried moving around the `clearCanvas()` but that didn’t work.
  ** It just made the whole square not show up at all.
  */

  if (playerX + DX > WIDTH || playerX + DX < 0)
    DX = 0;
  if (playerY + DY > HEIGHT || playerY + DY < 0)
    DY = 0;

  DX += playerX;
  DY += playerY;
}

function keyArrows(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    DX = -5;
    DY = 0;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    DX = 0;
    DY = -5;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    DX = 5;
    DY = 0;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    DX = 0;
    DY = 5;
  }
}

init();
```

I’m trying to get the blue square to move. Would this code even work to make the square move around once it’s actually drawn?

Comment: For canvas (or any graphical question really), it helps a lot to put a fiddle or other demo together. Also please post all of your `draw()` function contents. You probably want to look into `requestAnimationFrame()` as well.

Comment: Please don’t split your code in the middle of a function to explain something. Explain outside of the code, or in a JS comment, otherwise it’s just confusing.

Comment: You are clearing the canvas with `clearCanvas()`, but you aren’t drawing anything on the canvas after that. Obviously, your canvas is empty after that. You also aren’t using `DX` and `DY` anywhere.